# listcolumns and multidplyr

Tags: r, parallel-processing, dplyr

I am new to multidplyr. I have a dataset similar to what this creates:

```
library(multidplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)
f<-flights %>% group_by(month) %>% nest()
```

Now I´d like to do operations on each of these tibbles on different nodes.

```
cluster <- create_cluster(12)
f2<-partition(f,month,cluster=cluster)
```

everything seems ok until here, but when I do:

```
models<-f2 %>% 
  do(mod=lm(arr_delay~dey_delay,data=.))
```

I get the following error msg:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) : 
  12 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'arr_delay' not found
```

Now if I try

```
f2  %>% browser(.)
```

and then try .$ I do not have access to any of the columns-

Any ideas how these columns can be accessed?

Comment: Does `do` work without the nesting?

Comment: Yes- But I need the listcolumn structure to work because my dataset is nested with a total of 90 Mb of tibbles inside a datacolumn structure that cannot be flattened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question has two parts:

#### 1. Why are you getting an error using `do`?

The "proper" way to apply functions to a nested column (or "list column") is not to use `do`, but to use `map` instead. In this case, `multidplyr` isn't really important, since the normal `dplyr` code gives the same error.

```
f <- flights %>% group_by(month) %>% nest()    

models <- f %>% 
  do(mod = lm(arr_delay ~ dey_delay, data = .))
```

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'arr_delay' not found

Using `map` from `purrr` on the other hand works fine.

```
models <- f %>%
  mutate(model = purrr::map(data, ~ lm(arr_delay ~ dep_delay, data = .)))
```

Using your `multidplyr` code with `mutate` and `map` also works just fine.

#### 2. How can I view the data in a `party_df`?

You can't easily do that. Remember they are not available in your current R session, but on the nodes. You can access the names using this little utility function:

```
names.party_df <- function(x) {
  fun <- function(x) names(eval(x))
  multidplyr::cluster_call(x$cluster, fun, as.name(x$name))[[1]]
}
```

But to access the full data, you'll most likely need to `collect` your data again. Alternatively, in RStudio one can use `View`, but note that this doesn't work great on large data sets.

Comment: Hmmm... But in order for the dataset to be analysed simultaneously on the different clusters - should not the dataset be partitioned between the different clusters? And then the packages must also be distributed to each individual cluster. `models <- f %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, ~ lm(arr_delay ~ dep_delay, data = .)))` is just run on one node- right?

Comment: If `f` is a `party_df` different parts should be run on different nodes. So in your case you just replace `f` with `f2`.

Comment: I tried to replace f2 (which is a party_df) as follows: `models <- f2 %>% mutate(model = map(data, ~ lm(arr_delay ~ dep_delay, data = .)))
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) : 
  4 nodes produced errors; first error: could not find function "map"`

Comment: but when I `multidplyr::cluster_library(cluster,"purrr")`first - it works.

Comment: Great. Yes, sorry I had already loaded up a bunch of stuff on my cluster. In general you can just use `purrr::map` instead and all should be good.

Comment: is it possible to load custom functions written by myself  (not inside a package) to each node?

Comment: Yes use `multidplyr::cluster_assign_value()`.

Comment: Sorry for giving you a hardtime- appreciate your efforts. But if I have a custom function, helper, in my global environment that I want to assign to each node - `cluster_assign_value(cluster = cluster,name = "helper",helper)`?? When I do that it returns a column with values fun for each row (and in my original df/function it should be around 60 min for each row, but now the values are returned immediately.

Comment: I don't follow. Perhaps you can ask that as a new question.